# How can we get the api response time in react js , that is show in network tab?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

how can I display response time in react js, so I can compare response time with previews response time in react js?

Comment: are you using Axios?

Comment: The same way you would display any other value in React. What do you actually want to know? How to use React or how to get the response of a network request (which doesn't have to do anything with React)?